# How to iterate through one of the objects of jquery success?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have two objects passed from controller to view using `return Json(new {success = true , product, list});` I need only to iterate through 'product' object.Is it possible in jQuery?.I tried

```
 $.each(response, function (index, el) {        
});
```

then it also iterate through  'list' also.Following is the response from the controller in ajax success.

```
[Object, Object]------->values of product
 0: Object
     CategoryID: 0
     Description: null
     PhysicalPath: null
     ProductCategory: null
     ProductID: 41
     Title: "Woo Album"
     Tooltip: null
     VirtualPath: "~/Content/images/pro-cat-6.jpg"
1: Object
     CategoryID: 0
     Description: null
     PhysicalPath: null
     ProductCategory: null
     ProductID: 42
     Title: "EverShine Memories"
     Tooltip: null
     VirtualPath: "~/Content/images/pro1.jpg"

 [7, 8] ---->values of list
```

Comment: You need to provide what `product` and `list` looks like? moreover you got the index and so you can reach to desired element still you need to show us some data

Comment: can you post how your `response` object looks like?

Comment: [Object, Object]    0: ObjectCategoryID: 0Description: nullPhysicalPath: nullProductCategory: nullProductID: 41Title: "Woo Album"Tooltip: nullVirtualPath: "~/Content/images/pro-cat-6.jpg"__proto__:       Object1: ObjectCategoryID: 0Description: nullPhysicalPath: nullProductCategory: nullProductID: 42Title: "EverShine Memories"Tooltip: nullVirtualPath: "~/Content/images/pro1.jpg"__proto__: Objectlength: 2__proto__: Array[0]
ProductDisplay:286 [7, 8]

Comment: @neethu edit that in you'r question

Comment: I always name my Json objects as a rule of thumb, so change your Json to `return Json(new { success = true, product = product, list = list });` and then use Thiago's answer

Answer (score 1):

Is the object you want not a child of response? Shouldn't you just use `response.product` instead?

```
$.each(response.product, function (index, el) {        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead passing list through  `return Json(new {success = true , product, list});` `return Json(new {success = true , product, start=startIndex,end = endindex});` and in jquery used the variables as response.start and response.end